# C# BitmapSource - result is vertically flipped

Tags: c#, wpf, format, pixel

I am implementing a software in C#/WPF that is recording images from a camera.
The result is a Bitmap that I am copying into a byte[].

```
pixelFormat = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgr24;
int size = buffer.FrameType.BufferSize;
byte[] img = new byte[size];
Marshal.Copy(buffer.GetImageDataPtr(), img, 0, size);
```

I am creating a BitmapSource using this byte[] but the result I am getting is vertically flipped.

```
int stride = width * (pixelFormat.BitsPerPixel / 8);
image = BitmapSource.Create(width,
                             height,
                             96,
                             96,
                             pixelFormat,
                             BitmapPalettes.Gray256Transparent,
                             img,
                             stride);
```

[image: What I get from the camera directly]

[image: What I am getting from my software]

The point that can be a problem according to me is the PixelFormat. The camera is using the system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat whereas I am using System.Windows.Media.pixelformat.
The camera is using RGB24 but the documentation says it "uses BGR order for the RGB24 pixel format. The organization of the pixels in the image buffer is from left to right and bottom up. "

What can be the problem ? Am I using the wrong Pixel Format ?

Comment: Pixel format is not the problem, because you wouldn't see correct colors otherwise. It's just the order of scan lines in the original buffer. WPF BitmapSource is created top-down, whereas the buffer apparently contains scan lines in bottom-up order. Is there perhaps another method like `GetImageDataPtr` that gives you the other scan line order?

Comment: The camera doc is telling you everything you need to know. The pixel format determines how the red, green, and blue channels are organized in a pixel value, and you seem to have that correct (your images aren't exactly mirror images, but the colors are close enough to believe that the pixel format is correct). But the documentation also explains that it's sending you the data with the bottom row of pixels as the first scan line in the buffer. You can either copy the data to a new bitmap object, reversing the scan lines, or you can just use a transform to flip the bitmap when displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter Duniho and Clemens are right.
Here is the solution:

```
int size = buffer.FrameType.BufferSize;
int height = buffer.FrameType.Height;
byte[] img = new byte[size];
int lineSize = buffer.BytesPerLine;
//for each row of the image
for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
{
     //For each byte on a row
     for (int col = 0; col < lineSize; col++)
     {
           int newIndex = (size - (lineSize * (row + 1))) + col;
           img[newIndex] = buffer[col, row];
     }
}
```